# Metric properties.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

i have the following problem:

Let $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ and $y=(y_{1},...,y_{n})$ in $\mathbb{R^{n}}$.

let’s define $d(x,y)=|x_{i}-y_{i}|$ for some $i \leq n$ permanent.

What properties of metric does d have?

I have come to the conclusion that it is a metric, but according to the book I am following it says no, but does not mention an argument

I would be very grateful if you could tell me which property of metrica does not comply please, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n>1$, and you fix $i=1$ for the sake of concreteness. Then, $d(x,y) = |x_1-y_1|$. Let $x = (0, \dots, 0, 1)$ and $y = (0, \dots, 0, 0)$ Then, what is $d(x,y)$? Is $x=y$?